# Angular2 - DOM events lost on re-render when using Redux and uni-directional data flow

Tags: events, angular, redux, angular2-changedetection

I wasn't sure of the best way to word the title, but hopefully the description will clarify.

I have an Angular2 component that uses Redux for state management. 
That component uses `*ngFor` to render an array of small inputs with buttons like this. The "state" is something like this...

```js
// glossing over how I'd get this from the Redux store, 
// but assume we have an Immutable.js List of values, like this... 
let items = Immutable.fromJS([{value: foo}, {value: bar}, /*...etc*/ })
```

And the template renders that like so...

```
<input *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index" 
       type="text" 
       value="item.get('value')"
       (blur)="onBlur($event, i)">
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Add New Input</button>
```

When an input is focused and edited, then focus is moved away, the `onBlur($event)` callback is called, a redux action (ie: `"UPDATE_VALUE"`) is dispatched with the new value.

```js
onBlur($event, index) {
  let newValue = $event.target.value;
  this.ngRedux.dispatch({
    type: "UPDATE_VALUE",
    value: {index, newValue}
  });
}
```

And the reducer updates the value (using Immutable.js):

```js
case "UPDATE_VALUE": {
  let index = getIndex(action.value.index); // <-- just a helper function to get the index of the current value.
  return state.updateIn(["values", index], value => action.value.newValue);
}
```

The state is updated, so the component is re-rendered with the updated value.

When the button next to the input is clicked, the `onClick($event)` callback is fired which dispatches a different redux action (ie: `"ADD_VALUE"`), updates the state, and the component is re-rendered with a new blank input & button.

The problem comes up when the input is focused (editing) and the user clicks the button. The user intended to click the button, but because they happened to be focused on the field, it doesn't behave as expected. The `(blur)` event is fired first, so the input onBlur callback is fired, redux action dispatched, state updated, component re-rendered. BUT, the button `(click)` is lost, so the new input isn't created.

**Question:**
**Is there a way to keep track of the click event and trigger the second action after the re-render? Or, is there a way to somehow chain the redux actions so they happen in sequence before the re-render?**

Side-note - I've tried changing the `(click)` event to use `(mousedown)` which is triggered before the `(blur)` but that caused Angular (in devMode) to complain that the `@inputs` to the components were changed after being checked (the state changed during the change detection cycle). I didn't dig into that too deeply yet though. I'm hoping to find a solution using click and blur as is.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you modify the array you use for `*ngFor` in `onBlur($event)`? How does the array look like? Can you please show some code that demonstrates what `onBlur()` and `onClick()` do?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I just added some example code. All that really matters though is that both the blur and click cause the redux store state to change, so Angular2's change detection is triggered and the component is re-rendered (before the other event is handled). I'm more concerned with the broader idea of keeping track of user interaction events across a re-render, (if that's even possible). Or, if someone can suggest a different way to handle the interaction or component hierarchy that would avoid the issue altogether, that'd be great too.

Comment: If the same array instance is emitted then *ngFor shouldn't re-render. I don't know redux

Comment: One of the core pieces of Redux is immutability, so on every change of state, it creates a new copy of the state. If nothing changes in a given part of the state, it points to the same reference, but here - the array would be a new reference with the updates, so it should re-render.